# How to parse HTML file headings with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have an HTML file that I would like to parse in Ruby. The HTML file is very simple and only contains headers, links, and paragraphs. I am using Nokogiri to parse.

An example of an HTML file I am dealing with is:

```
<h1><a id="Dog_0"></a>Dog</h1>
<h2><a id="Washing_dogs_3"></a>Washing Dogs</h2>
<h3>Use soap</h3>
<h2><a id="Walking_dogs_1"></a>Walking Dogs</h2>
```

I need to treat `h1` headings as a parent, `h2` headings as children of the `h1` heading it is under, `h3` headings as children of the `h2` heading it is under, etc.

I want to store this information in an array of hashes, such that

```
[ { 
   h1: "Dog",
 link: "Dog_0",  
},{
   h1: "Dog",
   h2: "Washing Dogs",
   link: "Dog_0#Washing_dogs_3"
},{
   h1: "Dog",
   h2: "Washing Dogs",
   h3: "Use Soap",
   link: "Dog_0#Washing_dogs_3"
},{
   h1: "Dog",
   h2: "Walking Dogs"
   link: "Dog_0#Walking_dogs_1"
}]
```

Since none of the nodes are nested, I don't think I can use any of the useful methods for finding children. What I have so far is:

```
array_of_records = []; #Store the records in an array
desired_headings = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','p'] # headings used to split html into records

Dir.glob('*.html') { |html_file|


  nokogiri_object = File.open(html_file) { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f, nil, 'UTF-8') }

  nokogiri_object.traverse { |node|
   next unless desired_headings.include?(node.name)
   record = {}
   record[node.name.to_sym] = node.text.gsub(/[\r\n]/,'').split.join(" ")
   link = node.css('a')[0]

   record[:link] = link['id'] if !link.nil?

   array_of_records << record
  }
```

This code manages to capture what heading I am parsing and stores its contents in a hash as

```
 {heading: "content"}
```

but does not capture the parent-like information I need to capture.

Answer (score 1):

`traverse` is a good idea. You want to keep track of the latest h1, h2,h3, etc:...

```
@state = {}
records = []
nokogiri_object.traverse { |node|
  next unless desired_headings.include?(node.name)
  @state[node.name] = node.text
  case node.name
    when 'h1'
      records << {
        h1: @state['h1']
      }
    when 'h2'
      records << {
        h1: @state['h1'],
        h2: @state['h2'],
      }

  end
}
```

Comment: Hi! do you think you could check out the answer that I posted and give me suggestions on how I can improve it/fix the problem I'm having? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So, I came up with a solution that mostly works, except that it isn't storing my "records" in my array of records as I want it to. My solution is

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"
require "json"   

array_of_records = [] #Store the records in an array
desired_headings = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','p'] # headings used to split html into 
records

Dir.glob('./source/*.html') { |html_file|

  latest_headings = {}; # hash to store latest data from headings

  nokogiri_object = File.open(html_file) { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f, nil, 'UTF-8') }
  nokogiri_object.traverse { |node|

    next unless desired_headings.include?(node.name)

    case node.name
    when ("h1".."h4")

      @record = {}
      latest_headings[node.name] = node.text
      latest_headings.each { |key,value|
        @record[key] = value if key <= node.name
      }
      link = node.css('a')[0]
      link = link['id'] if !link.nil?
      @record['link'] = link if !link.nil?
    when "p"
      @record['content'] = node.text
    end

    array_of_records << @record
    puts @record

  } #end loop through nodes
 puts array_of_records    

} #end loop through files
```

I would expect that `puts @record` would print the same thing that `puts array_of_records` prints, but I find that `array_of_records` does not contain what `puts @record prints`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't add code in answers that "mostly works". Answers need to be working solutions. Also, don't prompt for additional commentary or information such as "Any suggestions?" in an answer. Answers are for that purpose only, whereas comments are for commentary and requesting additional information from the person asking.